# Error When Importing PDF into Word

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I need to perform multiple edits in a word document and based on search criteria then import the relevant PDF for that specific page. The file path I dynamically create as per specific data on the various pages. The code works fine if there are less that roughly 70 PDF files to import.

Once it gets to importing after around 70 PDF files then Word starts to give warning about not being able to undo the action which is about to be performed, even though i clear the Undo History after I have imported each PDF.

Then there is also an error which comes up with regards to the importing of the PDF, see image below:

[image]

But I can still open PDF document when this error occurs, if I stop my code and try to manually import the PDF it doesnt work. Only if I save the word document and then reopen it, can I import PDF documents into the word document again.

I believe it has something to do with all the actions being performed in Word.

Unfortunately I am not able to create a demo code which will give the same outputs for this question.

Why would PDF documents give an error when importing into Word?